# "print files" batch program

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, printing

I think this question is first time in `stackoverflow`. My problem is that I need to create batch program that will print any special document from given path. And send it to corresponded printer in the system.
For example I have 5 printers, and file named "menu.html"
command should be something like :

```
print file:"menu.html" for printer:"HP Printer - 5"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [Ask] then update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Compo i cannot understand what is the problem in my question?

Comment: We are here to help you fix your batch file problems not write them for you to your specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to set default printer:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "printer_name"
```

then you can try **[printJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/printJS.bat)** to print the file you want:

```
call printJS.bat menu.html
```

Comment: now I have one more question. How to run <RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "printer_name"> command directly from JavaScript with using ActiveXObject

Comment: I need something like < ActiveXObject("WSCRIPT.Shell").Run("my cmd command") >

Comment: @matthew - you want to be passed as argument to  printJS.bat ?  Or you want to hardcode it?

Comment: @matthew - why dont just add this in batch part of the script?

Comment: will your printJS.bat work on any browser, especially for Chrome and FF ?

Comment: the reason is that only IE supports "ActiveXObject" js class. I have no idea how to run it in Chrome and FF. Any Help please

Comment: @matthew - this is not a browser script .It uses WSH (which is not sandbox and have access to the file system and etc.) . You can download it from any browser though , but should be ran on the machine where it is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You used the incorrect syntax for PRINT. This is the corrected syntax.

```
PRINT [/D:device] [pathname(s)]
```

say that `menu.html` was in the `C:/` Directory, try it like this:

```
print c:\menu.html /c /d:lpt1
```

this would print `menu.html` to the parallel port `lpt1`.

(Please note that `print` would only print ASCII characters.)